# filter json in logstash

Tags: json, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a json file with records like this one

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Mills","date":"5/31/2014","email":"fmills0@feedburner.com","country":"France","city":"La Rochelle","latitude":"46.1667","longitude":"-1.15"
```

and I'm trying to filter the fields in logstash, unsuccessfully so far.
I tried the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/discover#) and the [grokconstructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/automatic) but cannot make it work. My last attempt is

```
input {
    file{
        path => ["C:/logstash-1.4.2/mock_data.json"]
        type => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    replace => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
  }
  json {
    source => "message"
    remove_field => "message"
  }
  mutate {
    convert => [ "latitude", "float" ]
    convert => [ "longitude","float" ]
  }
  mutate {
     rename => [ "latitude", "[location][lat]", "longitude", "[location][lon]" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  } 
  elasticsearch {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "test35"
  }
}
```

just for the latitude and longitude but that doesn't work. Any tutorial for logstash on Json particularly. Any help on this.
The output for the specific configuration file is

```
{
 "message" => "{\"id\":91,\"first_name\":\"Adam\",\"last_name\":\"Carr\",\"date\":\"11/14/2014\",\"email\":\"acarr2i@tinyurl.
com\",\"country\":\"Ghana\",\"city\":\"Mampong\",\"latitude\":\"7.06273\",\"longitude\":\"-1.4001\"},",
      "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2015-05-04T19:05:08.409Z",
       "host" => "Toshiba",
       "path" => "C:/logstash-1.4.2/mock_data.json",
        "tags" => [
             [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Updated for Alcanzar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geoip` filter is for adding lat/lon of an IP address to your data.

Putting all of the pieces together yields this:

```
filter {
  grok {
        match => [ 'message', '(?<body>\"id\":.*\"longitude\":\"[^"]+\")' ]
        add_field => [ "json_body", "{%{body}}" ]
  }
  json {
        source => "json_body"
        remove_field => ["message","body","json_body" ]
  }
  mutate {
    convert => [ "latitude", "float" ]
    convert => [ "longitude","float" ]
  }
  mutate {
     rename => [ "latitude", "[location][lat]", 
       "longitude", "[location][lon]" ]
  }
}
```

Which will generate an event that looks like this:

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-05-04T19:48:52.051Z",
          "host" => "xxxxxxxx",
            "id" => 1,
    "first_name" => "Frank",
     "last_name" => "Mills",
          "date" => "5/31/2014",
         "email" => "fmills0@feedburner.com",
       "country" => "France",
          "city" => "La Rochelle",
      "location" => {
        "lat" => 46.1667,
        "lon" => -1.15
    }
}
```

which should be exactly what you want.

Comment: I updated my question. Every time I try with different index. Thank you Alcanzar

Comment: I removed it and added in input codec => json because I got           "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ],
      "location" => [
        [0] 0.0,
        [1] 0.0
    ]

Comment: My input is accurate, there is no } which missing. I also tried mutate { replace => ["message","%{message}}"] }  but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Tested the full answer on my machine and it generates what should work.

Comment: After host I'm getting
          "path" => "C:/logstash-1.4.2/mock_data.json",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
} I don't get the data as you. Could you please tell me the version of ELK that you use? I use Elasticsearch 1.5.0, logstash 1.4.2 and Kibana 4.0.1

Comment: 1.4.2.  The only thing in my config file beyond what's posted is `input { stdin { } }` and `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }`.  I tested this on my mac with the command: ` cat foo | bin/logstash agent -f logstash.conf ` which is why it doesn't have a `path` in it.  Are there other lines in your file beyond the one that you posted (obviously there are because your example doesn't match the test data).

Comment: you need to remove the `codec => json` on your file input to do it how I've shown also

Comment: Updated my question. The whole configuration file is the above and the output as well. I run bin\logstash agent -f logstash.conf

Comment: your mutate doesn't match mine... there's two `}}` on mine

Comment: I'm getting the same error with  replace => [ "message", "%{message}}" ]

Comment: Your output doesn't match your input -- in you output you have a closing `},` but your input doesn't have that... So you need to clean up your file.

Comment: i "fixed" it -- it loads almost all of the records in that file -- except the ones that don't have longitude